# "CANNOT_EXCLUDE_DOCUMENT"

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I came across a really interesting error this week that some of our customers have reported.
When I send the below envelope with the [C# SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocuSign.eSign.dll/), I get the following error (Notice that the error doesn't even tell which document can't be excluded, not really helpful!!!!).

```
Error calling CreateEnvelope: {
  "errorCode": "CANNOT_EXCLUDE_DOCUMENT",
  "message": "This document cannot be excluded for this recipient. Recipient: C R cannot be excluded from Document:"
}
```

However, when I use Postman and send  a POST HTTP request, it works flawlessly.

I need to add that the request only fails with a specific email address (I am not really willing to share my customer's email, so I changed it to c.r@mailinator.com)

```
{
    "customFields": {
        "textCustomFields": [
            {
                "name": "PackageId",
                "value": "123456"
            }, {
                "name": "PackageType",
                "value": "Consumer"
            }, {
                "name": "FileUNC",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "PackageFolder",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "FormatType",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "FileName",
                "value": "Files - "
            }, {
                "name": "Transaction_Number",
                "value": "1"
            }, {
                "name": "Transaction_Date",
                "value": "07-18-2018"
            }, {
                "name": "Account_Number",
                "value": "123456"
            }, {
                "name": "Indexing_Type_Code",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Document1_ID",
                "value": "90"
            }, {
                "name": "Document1_Name",
                "value": "SD Assignment of Deposit Account:  CD Account Number 1234156 with Lender with an approximate balance"
            }, {
                "name": "Document1_Key",
                "value": "E90"
            }, {
                "name": "Document1_CustomField1",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Document1_CustomField2",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Document1_CustomField3",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "File_Name",
                "value": "LPL_1_SD ASSIGNMENT OF DEPOSIT ACCOUNT  CD ACCOUNT NUMBER 1234156 WITH LEND.PDF"
            }, {
                "name": "File_Path",
                "value": "\\"
            }, {
                "name": "File_Path_File_Name",
                "value": "\\LPL_1_SD ASSIGNMENT OF DEPOSIT ACCOUNT  CD ACCOUNT NUMBER 1234156 WITH LEND.PDF"
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower1_FirstName",
                "value": "JANE Q"
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower1_LastName",
                "value": "PUBLIC"
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower1_FullName",
                "value": "JANE Q PUBLIC"
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower1_TIN",
                "value": "777-58-2221"
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower1_Type",
                "value": "Individual"
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower1_CIF",
                "value": "JANE Q *PUBLIC^1^PUBLIC.0J3Q."
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower2_FirstName",
                "value": "JOHN Q"
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower2_LastName",
                "value": "PUBLIC"
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower2_FullName",
                "value": "JOHN Q PUBLIC"
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower2_TIN",
                "value": "777-58-2222"
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower2_Type",
                "value": "Individual"
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower2_CIF",
                "value": "JOHN Q *PUBLIC^0^PUBLIC.0J3Q."
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower3_FirstName",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower3_LastName",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower3_FullName",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower3_TIN",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower3_Type",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower3_CIF",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower4_FirstName",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower4_LastName",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower4_FullName",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower4_TIN",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower4_Type",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower4_CIF",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower5_FirstName",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower5_LastName",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower5_FullName",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower5_TIN",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower5_Type",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Borrower5_CIF",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Signer1_FirstName",
                "value": "JANE Q"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer1_LastName",
                "value": "PUBLIC"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer1_FullName",
                "value": "JANE Q PUBLIC"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer1_TIN",
                "value": "777-58-2221"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer1_Capacity",
                "value": "Borrower"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer2_FirstName",
                "value": "JOHN Q"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer2_LastName",
                "value": "PUBLIC"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer2_FullName",
                "value": "JOHN Q PUBLIC"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer2_TIN",
                "value": "777-58-2222"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer2_Capacity",
                "value": "Borrower"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer3_FirstName",
                "value": "C"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer3_LastName",
                "value": "R"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer3_FullName",
                "value": "C R"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer3_TIN",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Signer3_Capacity",
                "value": "LenderSigner"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer4_FirstName",
                "value": "JANE Q"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer4_LastName",
                "value": "PUBLIC"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer4_FullName",
                "value": "JANE Q PUBLIC"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer4_TIN",
                "value": "777-58-2221"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer4_Capacity",
                "value": "Grantor"
            }, {
                "name": "Signer5_FirstName",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Signer5_LastName",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Signer5_FullName",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Signer5_TIN",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Signer5_Capacity",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Document2_ID",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Document2_Name",
                "value": "Model Privacy Notice: JOHN Q PUBLIC"
            }, {
                "name": "Document2_Key",
                "value": "PRIVDIS2"
            }, {
                "name": "Document2_CustomField1",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Document2_CustomField2",
                "value": ""
            }, {
                "name": "Document2_CustomField3",
                "value": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentBase64": "base64string.....",
            "documentFields": [
                {
                    "name": "label",
                    "value": "DOCUMENT-216"
                }, {
                    "name": "Transaction_Number",
                    "value": "1"
                }, {
                    "name": "Transaction_Date",
                    "value": "07-18-2018"
                }, {
                    "name": "Account_Number",
                    "value": "123456"
                }, {
                    "name": "Indexing_Type_Code",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Document_ID",
                    "value": "90"
                }, {
                    "name": "Document_Name",
                    "value": "SD Assignment of Deposit Account:  CD Account Number 1234156 with Lender with an approximate balance of $10,000.00; owned by PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Document_Key",
                    "value": "E90"
                }, {
                    "name": "CustomField1",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "CustomField2",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "CustomField3",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "File_Name",
                    "value": "LPL_1_SD ASSIGNMENT OF DEPOSIT ACCOUNT  CD ACCOUNT NUMBER 1234156 WITH LEND.PDF"
                }, {
                    "name": "File_Path",
                    "value": "\\"
                }, {
                    "name": "File_Path_File_Name",
                    "value": "\\LPL_1_SD ASSIGNMENT OF DEPOSIT ACCOUNT  CD ACCOUNT NUMBER 1234156 WITH LEND.PDF"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower1_FirstName",
                    "value": "JANE Q"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower1_LastName",
                    "value": "PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower1_FullName",
                    "value": "JANE Q PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower1_TIN",
                    "value": "777-58-2221"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower1_Type",
                    "value": "Individual"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower1_CIF",
                    "value": "JANE Q *PUBLIC^1^PUBLIC.0J3Q."
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower2_FirstName",
                    "value": "JOHN Q"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower2_LastName",
                    "value": "PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower2_FullName",
                    "value": "JOHN Q PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower2_TIN",
                    "value": "777-58-2222"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower2_Type",
                    "value": "Individual"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower2_CIF",
                    "value": "JOHN Q *PUBLIC^0^PUBLIC.0J3Q."
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower3_FirstName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower3_LastName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower3_FullName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower3_TIN",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower3_Type",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower3_CIF",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower4_FirstName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower4_LastName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower4_FullName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower4_TIN",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower4_Type",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower4_CIF",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower5_FirstName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower5_LastName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower5_FullName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower5_TIN",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower5_Type",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower5_CIF",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer1_FirstName",
                    "value": "JANE Q"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer1_LastName",
                    "value": "PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer1_FullName",
                    "value": "JANE Q PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer1_TIN",
                    "value": "777-58-2221"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer1_Capacity",
                    "value": "Borrower"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer2_FirstName",
                    "value": "JOHN Q"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer2_LastName",
                    "value": "PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer2_FullName",
                    "value": "JOHN Q PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer2_TIN",
                    "value": "777-58-2222"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer2_Capacity",
                    "value": "Borrower"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer3_FirstName",
                    "value": "C"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer3_LastName",
                    "value": "R"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer3_FullName",
                    "value": "C R"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer3_TIN",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer3_Capacity",
                    "value": "LenderSigner"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer4_FirstName",
                    "value": "JANE Q"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer4_LastName",
                    "value": "PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer4_FullName",
                    "value": "JANE Q PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer4_TIN",
                    "value": "777-58-2221"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer4_Capacity",
                    "value": "Grantor"
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer5_FirstName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer5_LastName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer5_FullName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer5_TIN",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer5_Capacity",
                    "value": ""
                }
            ],
            "documentId": "1",
            "fileExtension": "PDF",
            "name": "LPL_1_SD ASSIGNMENT OF DEPOSIT ACCOUNT  CD ACCOUNT NUMBER 1234156 WITH LEND"
        }, {
            "documentBase64": "base64sstring",
            "documentFields": [
                {
                    "name": "label",
                    "value": "DOCUMENT-217"
                }, {
                    "name": "Transaction_Number",
                    "value": "1"
                }, {
                    "name": "Transaction_Date",
                    "value": "07-18-2018"
                }, {
                    "name": "Account_Number",
                    "value": "123456"
                }, {
                    "name": "Indexing_Type_Code",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Document_ID",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Document_Name",
                    "value": "Model Privacy Notice: JOHN Q PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Document_Key",
                    "value": "PRIVDIS2"
                }, {
                    "name": "CustomField1",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "CustomField2",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "CustomField3",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "File_Name",
                    "value": "LPL_1_MODEL PRIVACY NOTICE JOHN Q PUBLIC.PDF"
                }, {
                    "name": "File_Path",
                    "value": "\\"
                }, {
                    "name": "File_Path_File_Name",
                    "value": "\\LPL_1_MODEL PRIVACY NOTICE JOHN Q PUBLIC.PDF"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower1_FirstName",
                    "value": "JANE Q"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower1_LastName",
                    "value": "PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower1_FullName",
                    "value": "JANE Q PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower1_TIN",
                    "value": "777-58-2221"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower1_Type",
                    "value": "Individual"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower1_CIF",
                    "value": "JANE Q *PUBLIC^1^PUBLIC.0J3Q."
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower2_FirstName",
                    "value": "JOHN Q"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower2_LastName",
                    "value": "PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower2_FullName",
                    "value": "JOHN Q PUBLIC"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower2_TIN",
                    "value": "777-58-2222"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower2_Type",
                    "value": "Individual"
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower2_CIF",
                    "value": "JOHN Q *PUBLIC^0^PUBLIC.0J3Q."
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower3_FirstName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower3_LastName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower3_FullName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower3_TIN",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower3_Type",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower3_CIF",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower4_FirstName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower4_LastName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower4_FullName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower4_TIN",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower4_Type",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower4_CIF",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower5_FirstName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower5_LastName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower5_FullName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower5_TIN",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower5_Type",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Borrower5_CIF",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer1_FirstName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer1_LastName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer1_FullName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer1_TIN",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer1_Capacity",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer2_FirstName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer2_LastName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer2_FullName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer2_TIN",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer2_Capacity",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer3_FirstName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer3_LastName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer3_FullName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer3_TIN",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer3_Capacity",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer4_FirstName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer4_LastName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer4_FullName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer4_TIN",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer4_Capacity",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer5_FirstName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer5_LastName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer5_FullName",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer5_TIN",
                    "value": ""
                }, {
                    "name": "Signer5_Capacity",
                    "value": ""
                }
            ],
            "documentId": "2",
            "fileExtension": "PDF",
            "name": "LPL_1_MODEL PRIVACY NOTICE JOHN Q PUBLIC"
        }
    ],
    "emailSubject": "Loan Documents for Signature",
    "notification": {
        "expirations": {
            "expireAfter": "10",
            "expireEnabled": "True"
        }
    },
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "accessCode": "123456",
                "email": "brandi2860@mailinator.com",
                "excludedDocuments": [
                    "2"
                ],
                "name": "JANE Q PUBLIC",
                "recipientId": "bcb0014f-7d5a-4c04-a076-3257bfa2b205",
                "requireIdLookup": "False",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "dateSignedTabs": [
                        {
                            "bold": "True",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "3",
                            "recipientId": "bcb0014f-7d5a-4c04-a076-3257bfa2b205",
                            "xPosition": "148",
                            "yPosition": "787"
                        }, {
                            "bold": "True",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "3",
                            "recipientId": "bcb0014f-7d5a-4c04-a076-3257bfa2b205",
                            "xPosition": "148",
                            "yPosition": "729"
                        }
                    ],
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "3",
                            "recipientId": "bcb0014f-7d5a-4c04-a076-3257bfa2b205",
                            "scaleValue": "0.6",
                            "xPosition": "45",
                            "yPosition": "757"
                        }, {
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "3",
                            "recipientId": "bcb0014f-7d5a-4c04-a076-3257bfa2b205",
                            "scaleValue": "0.6",
                            "xPosition": "45",
                            "yPosition": "699"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                "accessCode": "123456",
                "email": "brandi2860@mailinator.com",
                "excludedDocuments": [],
                "name": "JOHN Q PUBLIC",
                "recipientId": "d7b9a190-b3be-440e-8167-25f548f71cb2",
                "requireIdLookup": "False",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "dateSignedTabs": [
                        {
                            "bold": "True",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "3",
                            "recipientId": "d7b9a190-b3be-440e-8167-25f548f71cb2",
                            "xPosition": "418",
                            "yPosition": "787"
                        }
                    ],
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "3",
                            "recipientId": "d7b9a190-b3be-440e-8167-25f548f71cb2",
                            "scaleValue": "0.6",
                            "xPosition": "315",
                            "yPosition": "757"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }, {
                "email": "c.r@mailinator.com",
                "excludedDocuments": [
                    "2"
                ],
                "name": "C R",
                "recipientId": "dd285a4d-22ce-4090-a1ba-7cd4524e5400",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "dateSignedTabs": [
                        {
                            "bold": "True",
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "3",
                            "recipientId": "dd285a4d-22ce-4090-a1ba-7cd4524e5400",
                            "xPosition": "148",
                            "yPosition": "877"
                        }
                    ],
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "documentId": "1",
                            "pageNumber": "3",
                            "recipientId": "dd285a4d-22ce-4090-a1ba-7cd4524e5400",
                            "scaleValue": "0.6",
                            "xPosition": "45",
                            "yPosition": "847"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "sent"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found the issue and solution.
It turns out that I was sending this transaction using the SOBO feature :

```
"SendOnBehalfOf"
```

And the sender was the same signer that I was trying to exclude a document from.
I believe DocuSign forbids excluding documents from the sender.
I will try to find documentation to back that statement but it seems to make sense considering the testing results I have experienced.